# Wrong marginnote position

Tags: tikz-pgf, marginnote, tikzmark

The following code does not give the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,marginnote}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\node[scale=1.3]{Text\marginnote{Note}};
\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

But if `1.3` is replace by `1` then everything works fine.

> How to fix this?

---

This does not work properly either

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\node[scale=-1]{Text\pgfmark{X}};
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw(pic cs:X)circle(.1);
\end{document}
```

Comment: You put a marginnote into a tikz node, i guess some value of the marginnote is scaled too. Why dont you simply write `\tikz\node[scale=1.3]{Text};\marginnote{Note}`?

Comment: I still could reproduce this problem. Looks like a bug to me. Make a bug report.